# Dart Template instantiate migrate from Web UI to Polymer

Tags: dart, polymer

Working old Web UI code:

```
<template instantiate="if view == 'dashboard'">
```

Not working Polymer code:

```
<p>{{view}}</p> <-- this is ok, prints: dashboard 
<template if="{{view == 'dashboard'}}"> <-- not work, if I change code to use bool property something like {{showDashboard}} then works ok.
```

What is the correct syntax? I can't find any example of instantiate with string comparison.

****Edit. More details:
Dart SDK version 0.7.3.1_r27487

html:

```
  <p>int: {{score}}</p>
  <template bind if="{{score == 4}}">
    <p>ins int: {{score}}</p>
  </template>
  <p>String: {{view}}</p>
  <template bind if="{{view == 'dashboard'}}">
     <p>ins String: {{view}}</p>
   </template>  
   <p>bool: {{showp}}</p>  
   <template bind if="{{showp}}">
     <p>ins bool: {{showp}}</p>
   </template>
```

dart:

```
class AppModel extends Object with ObservableMixin {
   @observable String view = "dashboard";
   @observable int score = 4;
   @observable bool showp = true;
}

void main() {
 query("#templ").model = new AppModel();
}
```

And output:

```
int: 4
String: dashboard
bool: true
ins bool: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Jacek, this works for me. In one of my apps, I have the following use of conditional rendering (variable names changed to match your example):

```dart
 <template bind if="{{view == 'dashboard'}}">
   <p>{{view}}</p>
 </template>
```

In this snippet, {{view}} renders only when score equals 4:

```dart
<template bind if="{{score == 4}}">
  <h2>Score: {{score}}</h2>
</template>
```

And the conditionals work even if you change `bind if` to just `if`.

Can you post more code? Perhaps the problem lies elsewhere.